# Linking failure using cygwin GCC as matlab mex compiler

Tags: matlab, gcc, cygwin

I'm trying to compile a piece of code which requires linking to matlab libraries in cygwin.

```
g++ -o mezcaglue.dll -shared -Wl,--out-implib,mezcaglue.lib -I/cygdrive/e/Matlab/R2014b/extern/include -L/cygdrive/e/EPICS/labca_3_4_2/lib/cygwin-x86_64    /cygdrive/e/Matlab/R2014b/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/libut.lib /cygdrive/e/Matlab/R2014b/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/libmx.lib /cygdrive/e/Matlab/R2014b/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/libmex.lib    -m64                ini.o multiEzca.o ctrlC-polled.o mglue.o   -lezcamt   -lpthread    -lm
```

I'm positive that all the *.o and *.lib files are in place, and yet I get errors like these.

```
/cygdrive/e/EPICS/labca_3_4_2/glue/O.cygwin-x86_64/../multiEzca.c:876: undefined reference to `mxMalloc'
/cygdrive/e/EPICS/labca_3_4_2/glue/O.cygwin-x86_64/../multiEzca.c:894: undefined reference to `mxFree'
multiEzca.o: In function `nativeType':
/cygdrive/e/EPICS/labca_3_4_2/glue/O.cygwin-x86_64/../multiEzca.c:382: undefined reference to `ca_field_type'
multiEzca.o: In function `multi_ezca_ts_cvt':
/cygdrive/e/EPICS/labca_3_4_2/glue/O.cygwin-x86_64/../multiEzca.c:294: undefined reference to `epicsTimeToTimespec'
multiEzca.o: In function `ezcaSetSeverityWarnLevel':
/cygdrive/e/EPICS/labca_3_4_2/glue/O.cygwin-x86_64/../multiEzca.c:1022: undefined reference to `mexPrintf'
```

I'm new to these gcc g++ cygwin stuffs so any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!